# eclipse - anonymous workspace loaded at first startup

Tags: eclipse

I don't know why, but now, when I launch eclipse (both via gui or command line, without any further options), it shows a workspace with no projects in it. So, to change workspace, I've to manually select the right one via menu. This anonymous workspace points to the home: any new project is automatically added to the home folder.

These are the steps that now I'm forcing to execute in order to have a working workspace:
 1. I launch eclipse (without any further options)
 2.     it shows the anonymous workspace (no projects and so on)
 3. I switch workspace File>Switch workspace>WhateverWorkspace
 4.     it shows the WhateverWorkspace

Furthermore, the anonymous workspace is shown only on the startup. I tried to see the list of workspaces in Windows>Preferences>General>Startup and Shutdown>Workspaces; no sign of this new workspace. I also tried to edit the /configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs file, but again no sign of the home workspace.
Also the "Prompt for workspace on startup" option doesn't work. What's going on?

Now, if I click on File>Switch workspace there is no track of the anonymous workspace. However, if, after step 2, I create a new project, this is created in the home directory. So, the anonymous workspace points to my home.

EDIT: This is the output of Help> Installation Details> Configuration

```
*** System properties:
applicationXMI=org.eclipse.ui.workbench/LegacyIDE.e4xmi
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
eclipse.commands=-os
linux
-ws
gtk
-arch
x86_64
-showsplash
/opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400/splash.bmp
-launcher
/opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name
Eclipse
--launcher.library
/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
-startup
/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata
4064800c
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm
/usr/bin/java
eclipse.home.location=file:/opt/eclipse/
eclipse.launcher=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
eclipse.launcher.name=Eclipse
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
eclipse.startTime=1413747456898
eclipse.stateSaveDelayInterval=30000
eclipse.vm=/usr/bin/java
eclipse.vmargs=-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar
/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
file.encoding=UTF-8
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
file.separator=/
gosh.args=--nointeractive
guice.disable.misplaced.annotation.check=true
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob
java.class.path=/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
java.class.version=52.0
java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
java.library.path=/usr/lib/nvidia-331/:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_25-b17
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version=1.8
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=[url]http://java.oracle.com/[/url]
java.vendor.url.bug=[url]http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/[/url]
java.version=1.8.0_25
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version=1.8
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version=25.25-b02
line.separator=

org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog
org.eclipse.debug.ui.breakpoints.toggleFactoriesUsed=true
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.splash.location=/opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400/splash.bmp
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
org.eclipse.m2e.log.dir=/home/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.useCairo=true
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
org.eclipse.update.resolution_url=
org.osgi.framework.executionenvironment=OSGi/Minimum-1.0,OSGi/Minimum-1.1,OSGi/Minimum-1.2,JavaSE/compact1-1.8,JavaSE/compact2-1.8,JavaSE/compact3-1.8,JRE-1.1,J2SE-1.2,J2SE-1.3,J2SE-1.4,J2SE-1.5,JavaSE-1.6,JavaSE-1.7,JavaSE-1.8
org.osgi.framework.language=en
org.osgi.framework.os.name=Linux
org.osgi.framework.os.version=3.13.0
org.osgi.framework.processor=x86-64
org.osgi.framework.system.capabilities=osgi.ee; osgi.ee="OSGi/Minimum"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JRE"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact1"; version:List<Version>="1.8",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact2"; version:List<Version>="1.8",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact3"; version:List<Version>="1.8"
org.osgi.framework.system.packages=<content truncated>
org.osgi.framework.uuid=402fed61-c757-0014-1f16-ed19c45e2914
org.osgi.framework.vendor=Eclipse
org.osgi.framework.version=1.8.0
org.osgi.supports.framework.extension=true
org.osgi.supports.framework.fragment=true
org.osgi.supports.framework.requirebundle=true
os.arch=amd64
os.name=Linux
os.version=3.13.0-37-generic
osgi.arch=x86_64
osgi.bundles=reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.1.v20140709-1414.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.1.100.weaving-hook-20140821.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.fx.osgi_1.0.0.201408150502.jar,reference:file:[email]org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.0.v20131217-1203.jar@1[/email]:start
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
osgi.compatibility.bootdelegation=true
osgi.configuration.area=file:/opt/eclipse/configuration/
osgi.configuration.area.default=null
osgi.framework=file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1.v20140909-1633.jar
osgi.framework.extensions=reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.1.v20140709-1414.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.1.100.weaving-hook-20140821.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.fx.osgi_1.0.0.201408150502.jar
osgi.framework.shape=jar
osgi.framework.useSystemProperties=true
osgi.frameworkClassPath=., file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.1.v20140709-1414.jar, file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.1.100.weaving-hook-20140821.jar, file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.fx.osgi_1.0.0.201408150502.jar
osgi.install.area=file:/opt/eclipse/
osgi.instance.area=file:/home/xxx/
osgi.instance.area.default=file:/home/xxx/
osgi.logfile=/home/xxx/.metadata/.log
osgi.nl=en_US
osgi.os=linux
osgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
osgi.splashLocation=/opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400/splash.bmp
osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.syspath=/opt/eclipse/plugins
osgi.tracefile=/home/xxx/.metadata/trace.log
osgi.user.area=null
osgi.user.area.default=null
osgi.ws=gtk
path.separator=:
securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom
sun.arch.data.model=64
sun.boot.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/classes
sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.cpu.isalist=
sun.desktop=gnome
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.java.command=/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400/splash.bmp -launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse -name Eclipse --launcher.library /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so -startup /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar --launcher.appendVmargs -exitdata 4064800c -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -vm /usr/bin/java -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.os.patch.level=unknown
user.country=US
user.dir=/home/xxx
user.home=/home/xxx
user.language=en
user.name=xxx
user.timezone=Europe/Rome
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come to this problem while developing Eclipse plugins. I experimented the same problem: with one version of my plugin all was OK, my Eclipse prompt me to choose workspace, and the with the following version the same problem as yours appeared.

The error was introducted by me, calling to `Plugin.getStateLocation()::IPath` from my bundle on activator startup, before Eclipse prompts the user to choose it.

This set the workspace programmatically to the default one (i.e. `~/workspace`), leaving no trace of it in files mentioned by you.

You'll have to **review your latest installed plugins and their preferences** (check if they can be lazy-initializated).

Hope it helps ^_~

Comment: well, actually I can't reproduce the problem at all: I was forced to reinstall eclipse. Thanks for your help btw.